# Update Excel Workbook When Cell Is Changed With Function

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula

I have one big workbook (workbook A) that runs a series of calculations based on the values of various cells. When I change the cells manually and press enter, the workbook calculates automatically. Now I am trying to change these values in A from a different workbook (workbook B) and read the resulting value from A into B, but running into an issue. I created a function that takes values from B and writes it into the correct cells in A, but it does not calculate A. It just reads into B the last value I calculated manually in A. Any help would be appreciated. Code below:

```
Function rwdiss(ByVal speed As Integer, torque As Integer) As Double
Dim pcb As Double

Evaluate "rwheat(" & speed & ", " & torque & ")"
rwdiss = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Top Level").Range("H64")

End Function


Sub rwheat(speed, torque)

Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Top Level").Range("F8").Value = speed
Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Top Level").Range("F12").Value = torque
Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Top Level").Range("H64").Calculate

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the relevant subprocedure in A at the end of the code?

Comment: don't think it's possible to update another cell from a UDF. Additionally are the calculations in A so complicated that you cannot just reproduce them in B.xlsx. This would be exponentially faster and avoid the need to have 2 workbooks open.

Comment: The cell updating is working, its the workbook calculation that is not. And yes, the calculations are complicated and reference sheets are are hidden and password protected so I cannot even replicate them if I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's not possible to force a recalculation of sheets from the UDF function (at least I can't).
You can trigger a workbook recalculation with a macro, such as an event macro. This can be controlled by a public variable, which is set to `True` when the function is called and to `False` after recalculation.
Code in a standard module:

```
Public flag As Boolean
Function rwdiss(ByVal speed As Integer, torque As Integer) As Double
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Evaluate "rwheat(" & speed & ", " & torque & ")"
    rwdiss = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Top Level").Range("H64").Value
End Function

Sub rwheat(speed, torque)
    With Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Top Level")
        .Range("F8").Value = speed
        .Range("F12").Value = torque
    End With
    flag = True
End Sub
```

Code in a `Worksheets(1)` module of the workbook "B.xlsm":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If flag Then
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .CalculateFull
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
        flag = False
    End If
End Sub
```

However, it would be worth considering a different approach, such as using a `Data Table`.